# I am trying to update a previously entered date in the past to the current date, if a condition is met

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have a worksheet that I use to help forecast cash flow.

Column V is a date that is initially the anticipated invoice date, and upon issuance of an invoice, becomes the actual invoice date.  Upon issuing a Purchase Order("D:D") or Invoice("F:F"), I manually enter the associated number and the current date is entered in the appropriate cells of that row, Purchase Order(With rCell.Offset(0, 11)){Column O} Invoice(With rCell.Offset(0, 16)){Column V}, to be referenced in other worksheets.

I've discovered the need to automatically make sure that the date in Column V is never in the past, which does occasionally occur.  I am having difficulty with this.  I need to only update Column V dates in the past, to the current date, IF Column F is empty.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Chris

This is what I have.  The first two routines run as desired.  The third is the current date issue, and does not function as expected.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rChange As Range

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set rChange = Intersect(Target, Range("D:D"))
    If Not rChange Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each rCell In rChange
            If rCell > "" Then
                With rCell.Offset(0, 11)
                    .Value = Now
                    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End If

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set rChange = Intersect(Target, Range("F:F"))
    If Not rChange Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each rCell In rChange
            If rCell > "" Then
                With rCell.Offset(0, 16)
                    .Value = Now
                    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End If

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
        Set rChange = Intersect(Target, Range("F:F"))
        If Not rChange Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            For Each rCell In rChange
                If rCell = "" Then
                    With rCell.Offset(0, 16)
                        If .Value < Now - 1 Then
                            .Value = Now
                            .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
                        End If
                    End With
                End If
            Next
        End If

ExitHandler:
    Set rCell = Nothing
    Set rChange = Nothing
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler

End Sub
```

Comment: Missing `End If` in your last code block after `If .Value < Now - 1 Then` (the error message is a bit misleading)

Comment: Thank you Tim, that eliminated the error.  The block does not perform the expected function though, is there a fault in my logic?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rChange As Range

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set rChange = Intersect(Target, Range("D:D"))
    If Not rChange Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each rCell In rChange
            If rCell > "" Then
                With rCell.Offset(0, 11)
                    .Value = Now
                    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End If

    '## combining your two loops into a single block ##
    Set rChange = Intersect(Target, Range("F:F"))
    If Not rChange Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each rCell In rChange
            With rCell.Offset(0, 16)
                .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
                If Len(rCell) > 0 Then
                    .Value = Now
                Else
                    If .Value < Now - 1 Then .Value = Now
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End If

ExitHandler:
    Set rCell = Nothing
    Set rChange = Nothing
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you again for your time and assistance Tim.  However, this still does not work for me.  In a blank *.xlsm workbook, I test with entering a character into F1.  V1 populates with today's date as desired.  In V2, I enter the past date 08/08/2008, as a representation of a date that ought to be changed to today's date.  No change, the same as my working document.  Running Excel 2016 on Windows 7.

Comment: Your code only responds to changes in columns D and F, so it's not going to do anything when you make a change in ColV...  I assumed from your description that the dates in V were all automatic.

Comment: Very good Tim, I revise from the point of view of an initial evaluation of V.  I appreciate your guidance!